# How to use a network video stream (from an ip webcam) as a webcam

Tags: webcam, skype, android, gtalk

I have a network video stream (mjpeg) from an android phone that acts as an ip webcam and I would like to use it as an actual webcam on my pc (for google talk, skype etc.)

Answer (score 1):

What you might use is an application that puts the ip input on a video4linux device:

- DroidCam

I use droidcam (http://www.dev47apps.com/). Install the droidcam app on android (free version should suffice) and the client on your ubuntu machine. Go to the folder in which you extracted the droidcam tar bal (tar.gz).

```
chmod u+x install
sudo ./install
```

Run it :

```
droidcam
```

It does all the work for you. The only thing you should provide is the (local) ip adress of your android device.

Test it using vlc:

```
vlc v4l2:///dev/video0
```

To let skype use the v42l device:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l2convert.so skype
```

This is what i do, but there might be other ways to convert to have an ip stream convert as a video device which can be displayed by skype,etc.